# Firestore Subcollection '!=' query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am aware Firestore doesn't support '!=' queries, but I was wondering if anybody has run into a similar situation as below:

Here is my db structure:

```
Posts -> postId -> postDocument -> likedBy -> uid
```

What I'm looking to do is only show posts that don't have the current user's uid in the 'likedBy' subcollection. That itself isn't possible, but I'm struggling to find even a semi-decent work around.

Currently I get all the posts and do the check locally to display the correct ones. Is this possible with perhaps a magic cloud function something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find success and use cases beyond this one by maintaining a user's feed and then only calling that at runtime. I utilize this method and have found I'm given a lot of freedom and Cloud Functions let me dictate what types of posts show and under what changes are new posts added to a user's feed.

The way I do it is I look for new posts via an onCreate cloud function and then look up who should see that post, etc. and add it to each of their feeds.

In your case I can see it being used by looking for new likes on a post. On new likes, it can remove the post from the user's feed.

An example of a function (edited for brevity) that I use to add posts to the user's follower's feeds. By grabbing using a collectionGroup query I can query the list of all users who follow the author of the post.

The schema looks like this:

```
Users (collection)
--- User1 (document)
------- Following (collection of people User1 is following)
----------- FollowingUser1 (document, contains a uid of "followed" user)
----------- FollowingUser2
```

and the Cloud Function:

```
exports.newReview =  functions.firestore
  .document('reviews/{reviewId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      var reviewId = context.params.reviewId
      var reviewData = snap.data()
      var userFollowers = db.collectionGroup('following').where('uid', '==', userId)
      var followingTransaction = db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return transaction.get(userFollowers).then(restDocs => {
          reviewData['added_via'] = 'following'
          restDocs.forEach(doc => {
            var followerId = doc.ref.parent.parent.id
            var followerRef = db.collection(`feeds/${followerId}/posts`).doc(reviewId)
            transaction.set(followerRef, reviewData);
          })
            return true
        }); 
      });

     return followingTransaction.then(values => {
          console.log(reviewData)
            var shouldPostToTwitter = reviewData.postToTwitter
            return Promise.resolve()
          }) .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Error deleting"));
          });
  });
```

DB look something look this:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL
});

const db = admin.firestore()
```

Comment: Gotcha, I have a similar functionality for building a 'friends feed'. Where I struggle with this is seeing how it will work with like 100k users. If I understand correct, it would be an additional write whenever a post is added to a user's feed. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right. The way I look at is is similar to what you added in your post with regard to it being an alternative to getting tons of posts before running logic on it client-side.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, I guess it is the lesser of two evils. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Dan, one follow up q. Do you have an example of a cloud function where you accomplish this? Working towards it, but struggling to get started. Thanks!

Comment: I've just updated my answer with code that I use in prod. I removed a lot of code but this should have the more general case you described.

Comment: Dan thanks so much for sharing. I think that will get me to where I need to be. I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Hi Dan, one more follow up (hopefully last). I am nearly there, I do have a question as to what the 'db' variable is declared as. I am getting a type error when I replaced that with functions.firestore.

Comment: You're a lifesavor. I'll give it a go, you really helped me a lot. Much appreciated!

Comment: You got it. The docs are here for that bit: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app

Comment: Thanks Dan, I am 'almost' there. I am running into an issue I've outlined in this question if you have a couple more cycles to take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175824/cloud-firestore-function-value-for-argument-documentpath-is-not-a-valid-resou . Thanks either ways!